# How to use rowdata variables in CCheckBoxColumn

Tags: yii, cgridview

I have grid generated with CGridView

```
'id'=>'grid',
'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
'selectableRows'=>2,
'dataProvider'=>$data,
'template'=>"{items}",
'rowCssClassExpression'=>'(($data["deleted"])?"deleted":"")',
'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
        'checkBoxHtmlOptions'=>array(
            'name'=>'checkbox[id][]',
            'class'=>'grid-checkbox',
            'data-aaa'=>'$data["aaa"]',
            'data-bbb'=>'$data["bbb"]',
        ),
    ),
```

I can get access to $data variable in rowCssClassExpression. But at the same time in 'checkBoxHtmlOptions' of CCheckBoxColumn $data is parsed as a string:

```
<input type="checkbox" ... data-aaa="($data["aaa"])" data-bbb="($data["bbb"])">
```

How can I get access to $data variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework does not support PHP expressions for htmlOptions array. Expressions are only supported for `checked` `cssClassExpression` `disabled` and `value` in `CCheckBoxColumn` See the documentation on properties of `CCheckBoxColumn` [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCheckBoxColumn)

The data for data cell is rendered like this

```
public function renderDataCell($row)
{
    $data=$this->grid->dataProvider->data[$row];
    $options=$this->htmlOptions;
    if($this->cssClassExpression!==null)
    {
        $class=$this->evaluateExpression($this->cssClassExpression,array('row'=>$row,'data'=>$data));
        if(!empty($class))
        {
            if(isset($options['class']))
                $options['class'].=' '.$class;
            else
                $options['class']=$class;
        }
    }
    echo CHtml::openTag('td',$options);
    $this->renderDataCellContent($row,$data);
    echo '</td>';
}
```

Refer [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridColumn.php#L138) for the source. 
As you can see only `cssClassExpression` is currently using the `evaluateExpression` function, which evaluates the `$data` based expression.

The only solution is extend the `CCheckBoxColumn` and overwrite the function You can do so by creating a file say `MyCheckBoxColumn` in your components folder like this

```
<?php 
class MyCheckBoxColumn extend CCheckBoxColumn { 

    public $htmlOptionsExpression; 

    public function renderDataCell($row)
    {
        $data=$this->grid->dataProvider->data[$row];
        $options=$this->htmlOptions;
        if($this->cssClassExpression!==null)
        {
            $class=$this->evaluateExpression($this->cssClassExpression,array('row'=>$row,'data'=>$data));
            if(!empty($class))
            {
                if(isset($options['class']))
                    $options['class'].=' '.$class;
                else
                    $options['class']=$class;
            }
        }
        if($this->htmlOptionsExpression != null){
             foreach ( $this->htmlOptionsExpression as $attribute => $optionExpression) {
                 $value=$this->evaluateExpression($optionsExpresion,array('row'=>$row,'data'=>$data));
                 $options[$attribute] = $value;
             }
        }
        echo CHtml::openTag('td',$options);
        $this->renderDataCellContent($row,$data);
        echo '</td>';
    }
}
```

and finally use this in your CGridview

```
'id'=>'grid',
'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
'selectableRows'=>2,
'dataProvider'=>$data,
'template'=>"{items}",
'rowCssClassExpression'=>'(($data["deleted"])?"deleted":"")',
'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'class'=>'MyCheckBoxColumn',
        'checkBoxHtmlOptions'=>array(
            'name'=>'checkbox[id][]',
            'class'=>'grid-checkbox',
        ),
        'htmlOptionsExpression'=>array(
            'data-aaa'=>'$data["aaa"]',
            'data-bbb'=>'$data["bbb"]',
        ),
    ),
 ),
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by extending class **CCheckBoxColumn**,

if you look at `protected function renderDataCellContent($row,$data)` , this is the function that needs to get overridden

you can then use `$this->evaluateExpression()` when needed to evaluate your expression